# Run a macro when node is published in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I need to run one of my macro when a page is published. I there any way to do this in umbraco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some events you can hook into. In your case you might use the `Document_AfterPublish()` event.

```
    static void Document_AfterPublish(Document sender,
 umbraco.cms.businesslogic.PublishEventArgs e)
            {
                // your code
            }

    // hook into the event
    Document.AfterPublish += 
                       new Document.PublishEventHandler(Document_AfterPublish);
```

Also look at [this](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/attaching-document-event-handlers) and [this](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/event-examples) links which could be helpful.